# Pegar horas pelo Datetime - Ionic 3

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic3

Preciso fazer um projeto para minha escola e não sei como pegar, pelo ion-datetime (Ionic 3), o valor dos horários que o usuário selecionar.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Bem-vindo, poderia [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/245669/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código ?

Comment: Veja se encontra o que precisa:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/